# Class 'app\Models\Job' not found why ? What to do?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this command line that doesn't work but I tried `namespace app\Models\Job;` or `use app\Models\Job;` or `namespace App\Models\Job;` or `use App\Models\Job;`.

I have also tried directly adding `App\Models\Job` to the command line but it didn't seem to work.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use app\Models\Job;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(['employer','verified'],['except'=>array('index','show','apply','allJobs','searchJobs','category')]);
    }
    
    public function index(){
        $jobs = Job::latest()->limit(5)->where('status',1)->get();
        $categories = Category::with('jobs')->paginate(5);
        
        $companies = Company::get()->random(6);
       
        return view('welcome',compact('jobs','
```

[image: Picture 1]

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id','company_id','title','slug','description','roles','category_id','position','address','type','status','last_date','number_of_vacancy','experience','gender','salary'];
    
    public function getRouteKeyName(){
        return 'slug';
    }
    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimeStamps();
    }

    public function checkApplication(){
        return \DB::table('job_user')->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('job_id',$this->id)->exists();
    }

    public function favorites(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class,'favourites','job_id','user_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }

    public function checkSaved(){
        return \DB::table('favourites')->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('job_id',$this->id)->exists();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Job model?

Comment: namespace isn't App\Models it is namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: But i tried. changing it.

Comment: Job::latest() dind't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Job; // change app to App
class JobController extends Controller
{...
```