# Laravel API controller not found - "Target class **** does not exist"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I know this was a bit of a breaking change in later versions and I have tried all of the methods I have found so far to rectify through stackoverflow and online and looked for spelling errors, but I am a little stuck here if anyone can help.

Laravel v8.6 - Fresh install

My api.php and the routes I've tried (Not at the same time obviously)

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use app\Http\Controllers\API\AssetTrackController;

//Route::get('/assettracking', [AssetTrackController::class, 'index']);
//Route::get('/assettracking', 'AssetTrackController@index');
//Route::resource('/assettracking', [AssetTrackController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/assettracking', [AssetTrackController::class, 'index']);
Route::resource('/assettracking', AssetTrackController::class)->only([
    'index'
]);
```

My controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Models\Assettrack;

class AssetTrackController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return DB::table('assettrack')->whereRaw('ID < 420000000')->get();
    }
```

I've tried adding to the RouteServiceProvider

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

Controller path : HeatMAP/app/Http/Controllers/API/AssetTrackController.php
api.php path: HeatMAP/routes/api.php

I've loooked and can't seem to work this out based on the solutions I've already found. I feel like this one is staring me right in the face. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68040394/class-app-models-job-not-found-why-what-to-do) one...

Answer (score 1):

Your controller namespace is wrong.

Assuming your controller is in this order of directories:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Api\AssetTrackController.php
```

you should fix it to:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
```

Comment: Thanks. Which namespace? In the RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: The namespace of the controller AssetTrackController, on the second image.

Comment: Now that you've changed the controller namespace, you need to change it in web.php to `use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AssetTrackController`;
Also check if the changes you made in RouteServiceProvider didn't affect the rest of the application, usually they are not necessary to mess with the routes in RouteServiceProvider, the router in laravel does everything individually.

Comment: Still not working... I can't understand why. Is there a way to debug and perhaps be able to provide more info?